# Spring @Async with Delay

Tags: spring, spring-annotations, spring-scheduled, spring-async

I am trying to define an Async method using Spring that needs to be called at the end of a synchronous function, like below:

```
void syncFunction() {
      ...

   asyncFuntion();
}


@Async 
void asyncFunction() {
      ...
}
```

I need to add a delay of 10 seconds before the execution of `asyncFunction` begins and would like to avoid adding `Thread.sleep()`. I've also explored `@Scheduled` annotation, but it doesn't seem to work for a `one-time` scheduled task. What is the best way to achieve this using Spring? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need a delay? You can use `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`

Comment: The `asyncFunction` depends on the completion of tasks from a third-party service invoked in `syncFunction`, hence requires a certain delay.  I am looking for something using Spring framework.

Comment: You won't find anything spring specific, since `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` already does what you want.